# Как организовать приватное и публичное API?

Tags: веб-программирование, rest, веб-сервер

Только начал углубляться в веб разработку. Не могу понять одной вещи. Допустим, на сайте есть приватные API, которые могут использоваться только самим сервером, и публичные, которые используют клиенты. Как это правильно организовать?

Comment: Не очень понял о "приватных API". Вы о API для связи фронтенда сайта с бэкэндом?

Comment: @JavascriptDev Именно

Comment: А что за сайт вы создаёте? Новостной, магазин или что?

Comment: @JavascriptDev Я это просто изучаю, чтобы потом применить